# Multiple Slave SPI on ESP8266 - PN532 and ILI9341

Tags: arduino, esp8266, spi

Im trying to interface ESP12-E module with ILI9341 display 320*240 And PN532 RFID reader on the same SPI bus. I have assigned SS Pins on different GPIO.

Im unable to Communicate with both. Display works perfectly in any conditions. But once i communicate with ILI9341 , the PN532 stops working and it will not respond until i restart the device even if i reinitialize it.

Any Help would be highly Appreciated
My Code :

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>
#include <UTFT.h>
UTFT lcd(ILI9341_S5P,15,D1,D3);

// If using the breakout with SPI, define the pins for SPI communication.
#define PN532_SS   (D4)
#define PN532_SCK  (D5)
#define PN532_MOSI (D7)
#define PN532_MISO (D6)

// If using the breakout or shield with I2C, define just the pins connected
// to the IRQ and reset lines.  Use the values below (2, 3) for the shield!
#define PN532_IRQ   (2)
#define PN532_RESET (3)  // Not connected by default on the NFC Shield

// Uncomment just _one_ line below depending on how your breakout or shield
// is connected to the Arduino:

// Use this line for a breakout with a SPI connection:
Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SCK, PN532_MISO, PN532_MOSI, PN532_SS);

// Use this line for a breakout with a hardware SPI connection.  Note that
// the PN532 SCK, MOSI, and MISO pins need to be connected to the Arduino's
// hardware SPI SCK, MOSI, and MISO pins.  On an Arduino Uno these are
// SCK = 13, MOSI = 11, MISO = 12.  The SS line can be any digital IO pin.
//Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SS);

// Or use this line for a breakout or shield with an I2C connection:
//Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_IRQ, PN532_RESET);
extern uint8_t BigFont[];

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello!");
  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    while (1); // halt
  }

  // Got ok data, print it out!
  Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
  Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);
  lcd.InitLCD();
    lcd.setColor ( 0, 0, 0 );
    lcd.fillRect(1,1,319,239);
    lcd.setColor ( 255, 255, 255 );
    lcd.fillRect(100,100,220,140);
  lcd.setFont ( BigFont );
  lcd.print(String("Scanning"),0,0);
  // Set the max number of retry attempts to read from a card
  // This prevents us from waiting forever for a card, which is
  // the default behaviour of the PN532.
  nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0xFF);

  // configure board to read RFID tags
  nfc.SAMConfig();

  Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A card");
}

void loop(void) {
  boolean success;
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
  uint8_t uidLength;                // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)

  // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
  // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
  // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0], &uidLength,25);

  if (success) {
    Serial.println("Found a card!");
    Serial.print("UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print("UID Value: ");
    for (uint8_t i=0; i < uidLength; i++) 
    {
      Serial.print(" 0x");Serial.print(uid[i], HEX); 
    }
    Serial.println("");
    // Wait 1 second before continuing
    delay(1000);
  }
  else
  {
    // PN532 probably timed out waiting for a card
    //Serial.println("Timed out waiting for a card");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've testing it a lot and figured out - The SPI bit-order is different, so you can not drive these two devices on the same SPI.

But you can use SW-SPI (bitbanging) for the NFC module, because it is not necessary to drive it fast. The TFT instead must be fast to have good update rates.

One Issue is still open on my setup:
the display did not show content, if you have an open serial terminal. But when it is closed, both TFT and NFC are working fine together.

Here is my code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>
#include <UTFT.h>

// NFC module
#define PN532_SCK   D1
#define PN532_MOSI  D2
#define PN532_MISO  D3
#define PN532_SS    D0
Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SCK, PN532_MISO, PN532_MOSI, PN532_SS);

// TFT display
// HSPI defines
#define TFT_SCK     D5
#define TFT_MOSI    D7
//#define TFT_MISO    D6 (not connected)
#define TFT_CS      D8
#define TFT_DC      D4
UTFT myGLCD(ILI9341_S5P, TFT_CS, -1, TFT_DC);

// Declare which fonts we will be using
extern uint8_t SmallFont[];
extern uint8_t BigFont[];

// forward declaration of helper function to get UID as HEX-String
void byteToHexString(String &dataString, byte *uidBuffer, byte bufferSize, String strSeperator);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 

  Serial.println("Initial nfc module");
  nfc.begin();
  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    while (1); // halt
  }

  // Got ok data, print it out!
  Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
  Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);

  // Set the max number of retry attempts to read from a card
  // This prevents us from waiting forever for a card, which is
  // the default behaviour of the PN532.
  nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0xFF);

  // configure board to read RFID tags
  nfc.SAMConfig();

  Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A card");
  Serial.println("Initial tft display");

  myGLCD.InitLCD();
  myGLCD.setColor(0, 0, 0);
  myGLCD.fillRect(1,1,319,239);
  myGLCD.setColor(255, 255, 255);
  myGLCD.setFont(BigFont);
  myGLCD.print(String("Scanning"),0,0);
}

void loop(void) {
  boolean success;
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
  uint8_t uidLength;                // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)

  // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
  // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
  // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid, &uidLength);
  //success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0], &uidLength,25);

  if (success) {
    Serial.println("Found a card!");
    Serial.print("UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print("UID Value: ");
    String strUID;
    // store UID as HEX-String to strUID and print it to display
    byteToHexString(strUID, uid, uidLength, "-");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println(strUID);
    myGLCD.print(strUID, CENTER, 50);
    myGLCD.setColor ( 255, 0, 0 );
    myGLCD.setFont ( BigFont );
    myGLCD.print(String("Scanning"),0,0);
    // Wait 1 second before continuing
    delay(1000);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Timed out or waiting for a card");
  }
}

// helper function to get UID as HEX-String
void byteToHexString(String &dataString, byte *uidBuffer, byte bufferSize, String strSeperator=":") {
  dataString = "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    if (i>0) {
      dataString += strSeperator;
      if (uidBuffer[i] < 0x10)
        dataString += String("0");
    }
    dataString += String(uidBuffer[i], HEX);
  }
  dataString.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.
Im not a big fan of bitbanging SPI.
I have tried several ways and tried re-initializing, etc.
Finally, i got it solved.

I dont know why, but when i re-initialize spi hardware after reading card, Both of the module works perfectly.

The code i added just after reading card:

```
    lcd._hw_special_init();
```

like:

```
    success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0], &uidLength,0);
    if (success) {
    lcd._hw_special_init();
    //Do the rest
    }
```